# How to access a database file on a remote machine via UCanAccess?

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am using the UCanAccess driver from http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

By using this driver I am able to access a local Access database file from Java like this:

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/pippo.mdb;memory=false");)
```

When I want to access an Access database file from a remote machine what would be the URL to pass to the `getConnection` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file on the remote machine must be accessible via Windows file sharing (or equivalent, e.g., a Samba share). The connection URL in your Java application will either use a mapped drive letter (as defined at the OS level)

```java
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://z:/somefolder/pippo.mdb);
```

or a UNC path

```java
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess:////servername/sharename/somefolder/pippo.mdb");
```

Comment: is there any possibility using hostname and port number

Comment: @MuralidharYaragalla - No.

Comment: @GordThompson How to connect to a MDB in a shared network location? I have shared network drive - 122.123.111.223 and there are folders in it. I used "jdbc:ucanaccess:////122.123.111.223/foldername/test.mdb" It doesn't work for me